# Atualização de Hessiana em método BFGS

Tags: python, algoritmo, matriz, machine-learning

Estou desenvolvendo o método de otimização não linear BFGS(Broyden-Fletcher-Goldfarb-Shanno) e estou com dificuldades em atualizar o valor da hessiana para minimizar a função. As variáveis de entrada para atualização de H (hessiana) são arrays, onde na atualização realizo operações de produto e etc. Abaixo segue o código da função e o seu respectivo retorno.

```
    def BFGS(f,g,x0,eps,maxiter=10, alfa=0.1):
x = x0
iteracao = 0
H = np.eye(len(x0))

while ln.norm(g(x),2) >= eps and iteracao < maxiter:
    p = -np.linalg.solve(H,g(x))
    s = alpha * p 
    print('Valor gradiente :', s)
    y = g(x+alpha*s) - g(x)
    x = x + s
    H = H + np.outer(y,y)/np.inner(y,s) - (H@np.outer(s,s)@H.T)/(s.T@H@s)
    print('Atualiza Hessiana: ', H)
    iteracao += 1
return x, iteracao

def f(x):
    return x[0]**2 + 2*x[1]**2 + (-2*x[0]*x[1] - 2*x[1])
```

Saída da função

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]